# settext Jtextarea every click

Tags: java, jbutton

I want to write in a jtextarea  each time i click the jButton .I don't know how to do it ,because IN the way i do it only prints one line .

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    jTextArea1.setText("Comienza el partido...." + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds
            + ":\n");

    jTextArea1.setText("Resultado:" + "  " + marcador1.MLocal() + "  " + marcador1.MVisitante()
            + "  " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "\n");

}
```

I want samething like that :

```
Match start!

local 1 -visitant 0

local 2-visitant 0

local 2-visitant 1

Thank you !
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to append text to your `JTextArea` rather then replace it every time with a call to setText().

You would do with this a call to [append()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Exactly ,that what i want.i will check append().